# Add text at the end of the specific lines? Notepad++ Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

How can I add text at the end of specific lines (only if a line starts with a specific word)
like this:

If a line starts with word `DATA`, then add this text at the end of the line: `"p:120 - 4 beats"`.

Example before:

```
FILE "H:\WAV\database 352968 0 1022501958
DATA t:untitled "example (98-01)"
FILE "H:\WAV\database352968 0 1022502044
DATA t:untitled "example (98-01)"
FILE "H:\WAV\database
DATA t:untitled "example (98-01)"
```

and I want this:

```
FILE "H:\WAV\database 352968 0 1022501958
DATA t:untitled "example (98-01)" "p:120 - 4 beats"
FILE "H:\WAV\database352968 0 1022502044
DATA t:untitled "example (98-01)" "p:120 - 4 beats"
FILE "H:\WAV\database
DATA t:untitled "example (98-01)" "p:120 - 4 beats"
```

Is there a way to do it in selected text area maybe with regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with a regex search and replace. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Search for:

```
^(DATA.*)
```

Replace with:

```
\1 "p:120 - 4 beats"
```

Set Search mode to "Regular Expression" and make sure that the ". matches newline" box is unchecked.

Explanation of the regex pattern:
`^` indicates that any match must be found at the start of a line.
`(DATA.*)` matches the text `DATA` and any text that follows on that line. The parentheses capture the matched text so that you can use it in the replacement text. (`\1` refers to this captured text.)

Comment: That exactly i want! Thank you very much. You saved me hours of manual entry!